# Automating AppSheet form to update specific Google Sheet cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-appsheet

I'm creating a simple inventory management system that updates when an item has been borrowed and returned by staff using AppSheet. I would like to know which staff_id has borrowed and returned which tool_id.

Currently in my Google Sheet for Staff, I have the columns staff_id, staff_name, tool1, tool2, tool3. Staff will use an AppSheet form to borrow and return tool_id.

Sample of google sheet
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8UfL.png)

Is there any way I can use App Script to update sheets after the borrow and return records have been updated?

To elaborate:
After borrowing record updated - We will search 'Staff' sheet for the staff_id under the 1st column, and update the tool_id under the 3rd column. If the 3rd column is filled, then fill the 4th. If 4th is filled, then the 5th. The form has a validation to prevent new entries if 5th is filled.

Sample of borrow form
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS4OO.png)

After return record updated - We will search 'Staff' sheet for tool_id under 3rd/4th/5th column, and just delete that cell (making it null)

Sample of return form
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIFvR.png)

Comment: `Is there any way?` Yes. If you would like a more detailed response, I respectfully suggest that you edit the question to include some sample data (Form responses as well as "Staff" sheet) as well as an example of the output of the borrowing record. Would you also clarify whether a user can borrow multiple tools unreturned tools; also, you are tracking Tool ID, how does this identify the tool?

Comment: Ok @Tedinoz I've updated the ask to have more clarity. I also updated the process a little to make it a little easier for a newbie to work with

Comment: Please do not provide sample data as an image; include the raw data in the body of the question. Also

Comment: `The form has a validation to prevent new entries if 5th is filled.` I don't understand your question or assumptions. If you have a form that can detect (in real-time??) whether a 5th column has been filled, then surely you are already updating the borrow and return records.

Comment: These are not real data. Its just how I would like the sheet to look. I can't achieve what I have shown on the excel, its all manually keyed in.

Comment: `Is there any way?` I'm very sorry. I misread the question and gave an incorrect/misleading comment. Specifically I misread `appsheet` >= `apps script`. "Is there a way". I don't know.